# webrtc in goinstant on ios

Tags: webrtc, goinstant, goinstant-platform

Trying to use the webrtc widget on an ipad and it is saying that the browser does not support webrtc.

Is there a work around that people are using for this? A number that people can call into on their phone.

What are the approaches taken to get people on a mobile device into the conference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there's no support for WebRTC on most mobile platforms, the notable exception at the moment is the latest version of Android running the Chrome browser.

Additionally, WebRTC does not have any native support for phone dial-in, however providers such as Twilio have begun development of WebRTC - phone interfaces (https://www.twilio.com/docs/client). Also, development of a dial-in feature would require the addition of a server to handle the authentication credentials associated with a service such as Twilio.

Video chat on the iPad/iPhone will likely be supported as soon as Apple's Safari browser adopts the WebRTC specification. However, telephone dial-in is not currently something on our immediate roadmap for the video chat widget.